# How do i close the Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code which Show/open a new Form :

In the gkh_Keydown event when i click on Ctrl + M it's showing/opening the new Form .
Now i want to do that when i click again Ctrl + M it will close the new Form .

When i click once to open the new Form it's going to this Form first :

```
public MagnifierMainForm(bool showMain)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (showMain == true)
            {

                GetConfiguration();

                //--- My Init ---
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                TopMost = true;
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

                mImageMagnifierMainControlPanel = Properties.Resources.magControlPanel20061222;

                if (mImageMagnifierMainControlPanel == null)
                    throw new Exception("Resource cannot be found!");

                Width = mImageMagnifierMainControlPanel.Width;
                Height = mImageMagnifierMainControlPanel.Height;

                HotSpot hsConfiguration = new HotSpot(new Rectangle(50, 15, 35, 30));
                hsConfiguration.OnMouseDown += new HotSpot.MouseEventDelegate(hsConfiguration_OnMouseDown);
                hsConfiguration.OnMouseUp += new HotSpot.MouseEventDelegate(hsConfiguration_OnMouseUp);
                hsConfiguration.OnMouseMove += new HotSpot.MouseEventDelegate(hsConfiguration_OnMouseMove);

                HotSpot hsMagnfier = new HotSpot(new Rectangle(10, 15, 30, 30));
                hsMagnfier.OnMouseMove += new HotSpot.MouseEventDelegate(hsMagnfier_OnMouseMove);
                hsMagnfier.OnMouseDown += new HotSpot.MouseEventDelegate(hsMagnfier_OnMouseDown);
                hsMagnfier.OnMouseUp += new HotSpot.MouseEventDelegate(hsMagnfier_OnMouseUp);

                HotSpot hsExit = new HotSpot(new Rectangle(95, 20, 15, 15));
                hsExit.OnMouseUp += new HotSpot.MouseEventDelegate(hsExit_OnMouseUp);

                mHotSpots.Add(hsConfiguration);
                mHotSpots.Add(hsMagnfier);
                mHotSpots.Add(hsExit);

                ShowInTaskbar = false;
                this.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                GetConfiguration();
                int x = mLastCursorPosition.X;
                int y = mLastCursorPosition.Y;
                MagnifierForm magnifier = new MagnifierForm(mConfiguration, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);//mLastCursorPosition);                
                magnifier.Show();
            }

        }
```

And since i  did false it's doing the else part :

```
GetConfiguration();
                    int x = mLastCursorPosition.X;
                    int y = mLastCursorPosition.Y;
                    MagnifierForm magnifier = new MagnifierForm(mConfiguration, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);//mLastCursorPosition);                
                    magnifier.Show();
```

magnifier.Show(); do show the new Form .

Now i want that if i do Ctrl + M again it will close the Form magnifier.Show();

So in the Form in the gkh_KeyDown event in the else part i did :

```
magnifierform.Close();
```

Added a new variable this time only for magnifierform and try to close it.
So in magnifierform i did :

```
public MagnifierForm(Configuration configuration, Point startPoint)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //--- My Init ---
            mConfiguration = configuration;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

            ShowInTaskbar = mConfiguration.ShowInTaskbar;
            TopMost = mConfiguration.TopMostWindow;
            Width = mConfiguration.MagnifierWidth;
            Height = mConfiguration.MagnifierHeight;

            // Make the window (the form) circular
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            gp.AddEllipse(ClientRectangle);
            Region = new Region(gp);

            mImageMagnifier = Properties.Resources.magnifierGlass;

            mTimer = new Timer();
            mTimer.Enabled = true;
            mTimer.Interval = 20;
            mTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(HandleTimer);

            mScreenImage = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            mStartPoint = startPoint;
            mTargetPoint = startPoint;

            if (mConfiguration.ShowInTaskbar)
                ShowInTaskbar = true;
            else
                ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }

        public MagnifierForm()
        {

        }
```

Added another instance that does nothing sincei  only want to close it.
But it never closed .

magnifierform is a variable of the MagnifierForm form i want to close it directly and not as before i used the other form MagnifierMainForm.

I just want to close it but it never closed. I used a breakpoint on the line :

```
magnifierform.Close();
```

On second Ctrl + M it's getting there but it dosen't close the MagnifierForm . Just does nothing.

EDIT

Tried something else now in the MagnifierForm i added :

```
public MagnifierForm()
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

In Form1 in the gkh_KeyDown event in the else side i changed it to :

```
else
                {
                    magnifierform = new MagnifierForm();
                }
```

So the instance i'm doing it on the second Ctrl + M
And again the breakpoint stop there but when i do continue it's not closing the Form .

Comment: is gkh_keydown firing when you press Ctrl-M the second time?

Comment: Tony yes Ctrl + M fire again when i make it seocnd time and it's getting to the ELSE part but i tried to do there magnifierform.Close then .Dispose and i see with the breakdown it's getting there and i did F11 and saw it's getting to the magnifierform designer or something whre it's disposing the form but in fact nothing haapen it's never get close. Maybe i need to create an event of Form Closing inside the MagnifierForm i try to close ?

Comment: Hard to say from here exactly where your problem is. @Idle_mind's suggestion is the way forward. You need to keep rigid control of the lifetime of the form. Me I'd have a class that managed the MagnifierForm, and take all references to the form out of your main form. Aside from anything else you could reuse it then with a simple interface.  Something looks to be holding onto it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if MagnifierMainForm() is already open you want to close it?...otherwise create a new instance and show it?  In your code that fires when Ctrl+M is pressed, do something like:

```
        Form frmToClose = null;
        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (frm is MagnifierMainForm)
            {
                frmToClose = frm;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (frmToClose != null)
        {
            frmToClose.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            // create a new instance of MagnifierMainForm() and display it
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method `form.Dispose();`